# How to access my member variables by $instance['name'] in PHP?

Tags: php, class

```
$instance = new className();
$instance['name']
```

How to make it work,an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your class implements [PHP's SPL ArrayAccess](https://phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL-ArrayAccess.html#1), then you will be able to reference class attributes in the manner you describe.

Taken from the tutorial I linked:

```
class book implements ArrayAccess {

    public $title;
    public $author;
    public $isbn;

    public function offsetExists($offset) {
        return isset($this->$offset);
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value) {
        $this->$offset = $value;
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset) {
        return $this->$offset;
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset) {
        unset($this->$offset);
    }
}

/*** a new class instance ***/
$book = new book;

/*** set some book properties ***/
$book['title']= 'Pro PHP';
$book['author'] = 'Kevin McArthur';
$book['isbn'] = 1590598199;

print_r($book);
```

Comment: +1,this is what I mean.Have u tried to do it by reflectionclass?

Answer (score 3):

```
$instance->name
```

if you want to convert object to an array you can check [this](http://snipplr.com/view/8242/convertion-array-to-object-object-to-array/).

Comment: Not what he was asking, isnt it?

Comment: BTW,how do you know I'm the he not the she?

Comment: @user198729 simply by being mostly ignorant about gender-neutral language. But if you want I will refer to you as *the OP* :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you  have defined your member variables, normally you can access them like this unless they are public:

```
$instance = new className();
$instance->name;
```

If however you have defined it as static variable, you need to access it like this:

```
$instance = new className();
$instance::$name;
```

If you meant to get variables like this (like array):

```
$instance = new className();
$instance['name'] // <----------- won't be like that exactly
```

You need to define an array in your class:

```
class myclass
{
  public $myarray = array();

  // more stuff to fill that array
}
```

Now you can access it like this:

```
$instance = new className();
$instance->myarray['name'];
```

But not like this still:

```
$instance = new className();
$instance['name']
```

Comment: Not wanting to be picky again, but No, it does not depend on how you define your member variables. A class has to implement ArrayAccess in order to provide access to members through array notation or inherit from a class implementing the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Your object must implement [ArrayAccess](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php). If you want to be able to access only the public properties (class variables) you will need to also use the [ReflectionClass](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) to check the access modifiers on the property.

Comment: Can you illustrate the ReflectionClass solution?

Answer (score 1):

cast the object as array

```
$instance = new className();
$arrayinstance=(array)$instance ;
$arrayinstance['name'] is the same as $instance->name
```

not sure if it was the exact question asked....